# using urllib2 in Python. Being detected and rejected by server

Tags: python, http, browser, urllib2

This code was working fine and reading html.
Then the site just stopped giving any data on read().  No error code.

It's because the web server has detected something unusual right?
(Before I figured setting the User Agent I had Error 403: Bad Behavior)

Does urllib2 have some noticeable signature that raises a flag?
Would switching to another library help?

I'm not doing anything suspicious.  I can't see any behavior difference between me using this library to read a page and using lynx browser.

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
search_url='http://www.google.com/?search=stackoverflow"'
raw = opener.open(search_url)
print raw.headers
print raw.read()
```

Comment: Are you sending many requests in quick succession? Some sites can detect that.

Comment: Google will decline to serve results to you if you've been making a number of requests in quick succession...although I thought they usually served up an error page in that case.  Are the `headers` empty also?

Comment: Have you considered respecting their robots.txt?

Answer (score 2):

Given your print statement, I assume you are doing this over Python2.x
I ran the same thing on my system and it works, irrespective of setting the user-agent. What David Robinson suggested might have something to do over here.

On another note, I have personally used, the following example snippet

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.voidspace.org.uk')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Multiple times, over multiple use cases and have never encountered your error.

Comment: I've done about 10 reads on the same page in the space of an hour.  The header is not empty.  What can I look at for clues?

Comment: If possible I would suggest doing the same thing from a different location/ISP, often a certain IP range might give an issue.
Even 100 request in half hour shouldn't be an issue because of you alone.

Comment: I can get the same page from lynx browser or Chrome browser successfully.  Google definitely dislikes the script.  I get status code 200 success btw.

Comment: @Morgan:  Google doesn't want you to run scripts against their people-facing front end.  Google has an API for web searches https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview.  After a certain level of usage you'll need to start paying for the results.

Comment: That's the answer Steve.  Still want to know how they determine it's a script!

Answer (score 0):

Try using mechanize instead of plain urllib2 for crawling search engines, it mimics better a browser's behaviour.